# Unexpected token J in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at __webpack_exports__.default (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/mail.js:4:21)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, next.js

I don't understand what is wrong here or what's causing the problem

I'm trying to build a contact form here and when I **console.log()** the FormData here it returns an empty array and gives `Internal Server error 500`[check out the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpcqv.png). I'm posting a link because it does allow me to share a pic since I've low reputation.

My pages/contact.js contains data of a **POST REQUEST** of the input fields
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYvIk.png)

Finally error in my IDE's terminal

[my terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSrMP.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not providing **pictures** of text.

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing the `JSON.stringify` string as the data. You are not calling the `JSON.stringify` method. And you also need to use parenthesis when you call it, not brackets.

the `body: "JSON.stringify[formData]"`

to `body: JSON.stringify( formData )`

Comment: Alright, thank you! The error is gone.  But still, it's returning an empty array when I hit the submit button in my contact form :(

Comment: @Mahijendra if this fixed this issue and you now have a different problem, accept this answer and create a new question.